# Inequality validation checking based on assumption in sympy

Tags: sympy

I want to check whether inequality `a<f` hold based on the following assumptions

```
a<b
b=d
d=e
e<f
```

What is the best way to verify whether inequality `a<f` hold based on those assumption.

I can substitute equalizes and Simplify `a<b` as follows

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a=Symbol('a')
>>> b=Symbol('b')
>>> c=Symbol('c')
>>> d=Symbol('d')
>>> f=a<b
>>> f.subs({b:c,c:d}).simplify()
a < d
```

Looking forward for suggestion

Comment: SymPy doesn't currently have algorithms to solve these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply